# How to use NSUndoManager on macOS 10.12?

Tags: core-data, xcode8, macos-sierra, nsundomanager

I read in the documentation that NSManagedObjectContext now defaults to a nil NSUndoManager on macOS. How can I set NSUndoManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an undo manager and assign it to the managed object context.

```
NSUndoManager *undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
managedObjectContext.undoManager = undoManager;
```